# Why doesn't this type guard work in this ternary expression?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
function isArray(v: any): v is any[] {
    return Array.isArray(v);
}

type Settings = {
    [key: string]: string | string[]
}

function myfunc(settings: Settings) {
    Object.keys(settings).forEach(key => (
        (isArray(settings[key]))
            ? settings[key].forEach(val => console.log(val))
            : console.log(settings[key])
    ));
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgQQE4YIYE8AUAbgFyLZi4CUphyKZFA2gLqIDeAUIt4hgKZQQGJJhy4AdKlF4ilANwcAvhw5RcABz6IAygNhgA5vQC87Lj0YBrPrlIooGGIeZ2HTg4gA+ie48MslFVBIWAREAFtcYIh8FD13FFJdKH0jSjMeRAB5ACMAKz5ocWtcFFj4wxRKcWA4DABRbAgAC3wSxGMAPkR8c0zufCksGTiUhKsbZkpKPv7MgH4fCqMJ3GYausaWomwAGw7uiAQUOF2+cV24Ax3d6dm57lIjsBOzi6vyscrVqdnphUUQA)

At `settings[key].forEach(` I'm seeing the message:

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
>     Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.

So why doesn't the `isArray` type guard work?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not using `.map()`, I'm using `.forEach()`. But the type guard does not work for either of them. Edit: Sorry, now I see. But that's still not the point of the question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I changed that now, but the question remains.

Comment: Fair point, I would also comment on that in a code review.

Comment: I would guess that the typescript linter just isn't "smart" enough. It just sees `settings[key].forEach(...)` and `settings[key]` is defined as `string[]` and therefor shows the warning.

Comment: So generally speaking, type guards do not work for ternary expressions? I can't be the first one to notice this, but I also can't find an issue for this on Github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type guards don't work with getter expressions, like here

```
    (isArray(settings[key]))  // (1)
        ? settings[key].forEach(val => console.log(val)) // (2)
```

because the compiler cannot be sure that `settings[key]` in (1) and (2) are the same thing. You have to assign it to a temp variable first:

```
    let temp = settings[key];
    (isArray(temp))
        ? temp.forEach(val => console.log(val))
        : console.log(temp)
```

Comment: That actually makes sense. Is there some way to express with types that an object will not have any getters?

Comment: I think in my case (iterating over the enumerable properties of an object) the simplest way to assign the property to a variable is to just use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()`.

Comment: @LarsNyström: yes, this would be a cleaner way.